# MYSQL import (Different version)

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, centos, corruption

I have a user Database that I managed to recover after a Hardware failure, however when I try and import it to my new MYSQL database in PHPMyAdmin it says that it cannot read it due to it being for another version of MYSQL. I have no idea what version of MYSQL my older corrupted server was?

I'm having to get my customers to manually re-register and me setting everything up manually again which is going to take hours.

The file I have is "users.MYD". Is there any way of importing ignoring compatibility issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to install the same version of MySQL that you previously had, stick that MYD file (and others) into it, start MySQL, mysqldump out the data and then insert that into your new MySQL database.

[ appended ]

After much searching around, it does appear that the problem here is that the old database was a MySQL 4.1 database (or older), and you can't install MYD/frm files from a 4.1 db on to a MySQL 5.0 database - the way to do that is to mysqldump the data and import it into the new database.  The challenge here therefore is to find a MySQL 4.1 database, which probably involves installing a very old operating system.

Comment: Problem is, I don't know what the version was? Is there anyway to find out? I don't have that system anymore as it was fully re-installed.

Comment: I suspected that might be the problem you would face.  How old was the database that crashed?  What version is the database that you've attempted to load it into?

Comment: Sorry, hold on... am I right in understanding from your original question that you attempted to pass in the MYD file to phpMyAdmin?  If so, that's why it failed - you need to put it in the filesystem, such as /var/lib/mysql/data/

Comment: MYSQL version 14.14 Also I'm not sure I'd say around 2 months max.

Edit: Yeah I put the MYD file into the database manually into that folder, but that's the message phpmyadmin says when I try and browse the user table.

Comment: MySQL isn't at version 14.  It's only at version 5.5.  Did you put the frm file in the folder at the same time as the MYD file?

Comment: [root@svrj1 ~]# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
[root@svrj1 ~]#

Comment: Sorry, that will be version 5.1.66 then.

Comment: Yep, 5.1.  But what about the frm file?

Comment: I tried adding it again by replacing the users.MYD file and it said on PHPMyAdmin that the table has "crashed" and should be repaired?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19604/discussion-between-user1372896-and-kenny)